# How to concatenate two models in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I wanted to use this model but we cannot use merge anymore.

```
image_model = Sequential([
    Dense(embedding_size, input_shape=(2048,), activation='relu'),
    RepeatVector(max_len)
])
caption_model = Sequential([
    Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=max_len),
    LSTM(256, return_sequences=True),
    TimeDistributed(Dense(300))
])
final_model = Sequential([
    Merge([image_model, caption_model], mode='concat', concat_axis=1),
    Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False)),
    Dense(vocab_size),
    Activation('softmax')
])
```

i rewrote this in following way,excluding final_model:

```
image_in = Input(shape=(2048,))
caption_in = Input(shape=(max_len, vocab_size))
merged = concatenate([image_model(image_in), caption_model(caption_in)],axis=0)
latent = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False))(merged)
out = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(latent)
final_model = Model([image_in, caption_in], out)

final_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(), metrics=['accuracy'])
final_model.summary()
```

This also gave me:

```
ValueError: "input_length" is 40, but received input has shape (None, 40, 8256).
```

Can anyone help to fix it?
source:https://github.com/yashk2810/Image-Captioning/blob/master/Image%20Captioning%20InceptionV3.ipynb

Comment: what is the value of `maxlen`, `embedding_size`, and `vocab_size`?

Comment: embedding_size=300,max_len=40,vocab_size=8256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should define the caption_in as 2D: `Input(shape=(max_len,))`. in your case, the concatenation must be operated on the last axis: `axis=-1`. the rest seems ok

```
embedding_size=300
max_len=40
vocab_size=8256

image_model = Sequential([
    Dense(embedding_size, input_shape=(2048,), activation='relu'),
    RepeatVector(max_len)
])
caption_model = Sequential([
    Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=max_len),
    LSTM(256, return_sequences=True),
    TimeDistributed(Dense(300))
])

image_in = Input(shape=(2048,))
caption_in = Input(shape=(max_len,))
merged = concatenate([image_model(image_in), caption_model(caption_in)],axis=-1)
latent = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False))(merged)
out = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(latent)
final_model = Model([image_in, caption_in], out)

final_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(), metrics=['accuracy'])
final_model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Marco, the issue had to do with the `input_length` parameter. You can join the two models as such:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy.random import randint 

embedding_size = 300
max_len = 40
vocab_size = 8256

image_model = Sequential([
    Dense(embedding_size, input_shape=(2048,), activation='relu'),
    RepeatVector(max_len)
])
caption_model = Sequential([
    Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=max_len),
    LSTM(256, return_sequences=True),
    TimeDistributed(Dense(300))
])


class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, image, caption):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.caption = caption
        self.concatenate = Concatenate()
        self.lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False))
        self.dense = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, **kwargs):
        a = self.image(inputs['image'])
        b = self.caption(inputs['caption'])
        x = self.concatenate([a, b])
        x = self.lstm(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        return x

model = MyModel(image_model, caption_model)

model({'image': randint(0, 10, (1, 2048)), 
       'caption': randint(0, 100, (1, 40))})
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 8256), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.00011554, 0.00014183, 0.00011184, ..., 0.0001064 , 0.00014344,
        0.00012491]], dtype=float32)>
```